# Accessing Models in Backbone Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am struggling to access the models in my collection despite reading all kinds of solutions to this issue and trying them out - there is obviously something I am not getting - PLEASE HELP!

I have a collection where the data comes from an XML file as follows:

```
define([
    'underscore', 
    'backbone',
    'localstorage',
    'models/script/ScriptModel'
], function(_, Backbone, LocalStorage, ScriptModel) {

    var ScriptsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 

        model : ScriptModel,

        url: '/data/script.xml',

        parse: function (data) {
        var parsed = [];
            $(data).find('play').each(function (index) {
                var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                var author = $(this).find('author').text();
                parsed.push({
                    title: title,
                    author: author
                });
            });

            return parsed;
        },

        fetch: function (options) {
            options = options || {};
            options.dataType = "xml";

            return Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this, options);
        }
    });

    return ScriptsCollection;
});
```

This all seems to be working okay, then in my view I do the following:

```
define([
    'jquery', 
    'underscore', 
    'backbone',
    'views/settings/SettingsView',
    'models/script/ScriptModel', 
    'collections/scripts/ScriptsCollection',    
    'text!templates/script/scriptTemplate.html'
],    
    function($, _, Backbone, SettingsView, ScriptModel, ScriptsCollection,  scriptTemplate) {

    var ScriptView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : $("#container"),

        initialize: function(){
            this.collection = new ScriptsCollection();    
            this.collection.fetch();
        },

        render : function() {            
            this.$el.html(scriptTemplate);

            //add the settings view
            var settingsView = new SettingsView();
            settingsView.render();            
        }
    });

    return ScriptView;
});
```

Now if I console log 'this.collection' I can see:

```
child {length: 0, models: Array[0], _byId: Object, constructor: function, model: function…}
    _byId: Object
    length: 1
    models: Array[1]
    0: child
    _changing: false
    _events: Object
    _pending: false
    _previousAttributes: Object
    attributes: Object
    author: "Eric and Ernie"
    title: "The Play Wot I Wrote"
    __proto__: Object
    changed: Object
    cid: "c3"
    collection: child
    __proto__: Surrogate
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
    __proto__: Surrogate
```

where in 'models' I can see my data in 'attributes' but if I log 'this.collection.models' I see an empty array. I can also see that the length of models is 0 so I am confused by this??

I just can't seem to figure out why this is the case though my guess is I am just missing something fundamental here?? - Backbone noob I'm afraid!

Any ideas........anyone??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your code:
var ScriptView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : $("#container"),

```
    initialize: function(){
        this.collection = new ScriptsCollection();    
        this.collection.fetch({reset: true});
        var that = this;
        this.collection.bind('reset', that.render, that.collection);
    },

    render : function() {            
        this.$el.html(scriptTemplate);
        console.log(this.collection);
        //add the settings view
        var settingsView = new SettingsView();
        settingsView.render();            
    }
});
```

Now check collection in render method

Comment: Fetch handler changed in backbone 1.0. Refer link: http://backbonejs.org/#changelog

Comment: Hi SR5 & thanks. unfortunately I am getting the same when I log in render method as suggested. I am now also getting an error of '**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'html' of undefined**' caused by the line '**this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);**'. I think I read somewhere that reset is called by fetch in older versions of Backbone - I'm using 1.1.0 - could that be part of the problem I wonder?

Comment: Updated the answer. Pleasee check. Did the same changes and I got the collection in render method.

Comment: Catch was render being called before collection fetched data.